# Remove irremovable label from slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In my presentation I have on the bottom left of every slide "confidential & proprietary" mark. This is not footer, footer in my presentation is empty. 
How to remove this mark from all the slides?

Comment: Are these watermarks in an image? Or did powerpoint add them on it's own, any idea why?

Comment: No, this is not a watermark. This label is embedded to the template and that why it is at all slides

Comment: Hmm... could just not use that template, or try edit them out of the template

Comment: I already make all the presentation with this template. All that I can do is to change design, not template. I don't want to CopyPaste all the hundreds of slides from one template to another one. So, the question is: what is that secret label that can't be removed?

Comment: Have you tried editing the master slide?

Comment: Yes, I go to the View->Slide master, see the irremovable label on all slides but can't remove it also

Comment: are you sure it is on the master ? is it on a separate background? You should be able to find where this logo / design is located or make a new presentation...

Comment: Post an otherwise blank example slide someplace where we can download and examine it.

Comment: I already find a solution-the label was printed in the background image

Answer (score 2):

I already find a solution-the label was printed in the background image